# Empty navigation bar after Login Screen

Tags: ios, facebook

Hello I am currently stuck with navigation bar issue on my project. I have a Facebook login which on successful login, takes user to the activity feed connected with a tab bar controller. On successful login I am using the following code, to take user to a particular screen:

```
     func controllingNavigationAfterLogin()
    {   let vcPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerStor‌​yboardID") as! YourViewControllerClassName 
       let vcPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcPage) 
      let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vcPageNav 
    }
```

[image: storyboard]

Identifier here represents storyboard id of tabbarcontroller. Till now everything works fine but my navigation title goes missing for some reason which I am failing to find. If someone can help me with this it will be great!

[image: Activity Feed view controller with no Navigation title in Simulator]

[image: Activity Feed view controller with title in IB]

Comment: next screen you want to display tab bar controller ?

Comment: My IB is something like this :

Login Screen -> Tab bar controller which has three VC among one is Activity feed.  When navigated here I am seeing empty navigation bar which is connected to navigation controller.

Comment: ok pls wait i will solve your problem

Comment: which code u use goto next tab bar screen

Comment: You should edit your post and past this code in here and make a  full Storyboard capture

Comment: I have added my storyboard for a clear view of my project and updated the function which I am using to transfer to a particular screen on successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set StoryboardID for your tabBarController and try this:

```
let tabBarController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar​Controller")
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you :)